# How to deal with ties when conducting Wilcoxon signed rank test?

Tags: r, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a paired data with a small sample size of 21 and I'd like to conduct Wilcoxon signed rank test using R. `wilcox.test` from the base stat package gives results with a warning message that says that exact p-value cannot be computed with ties and zeroes. Since my data is small, I cannot afford to discard the ties. I'm also aware of coin package that has `wilcoxsign_test` function. I'm not sure if it gives the exact p-value.

This is how the data looks like: 

    `Q1.response   Q2.response  avg_diff
1          2.5         2.0     -0.5
2          3.5         1.5     -2.0
3          2.0         2.0      0.0
4          1.5         4.0      2.5
5          4.0         3.5     -0.5
6          3.5         4.0      0.5
7          3.0         3.0      0.0
8          2.5         2.0     -0.5
9          4.0         3.5     -0.5
10         3.5         2.5     -1.0
11         3.5         3.5      0.0
12         2.5         1.5     -1.0
13         2.0         2.0      0.0
14         3.0         3.0      0.0
15         1.5         2.5      1.0
16         1.5         1.5      0.0
17         1.5         1.5      0.0
18         2.0         2.5      0.5
19         3.5         2.5     -1.0
20         1.5         1.5      0.0
21         3.0         2.0     -1.0`

As you can see, there are several ties. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a one- or two-sided test?

Comment: I'm planning to do both one-sided and two-sided. But first, I'd want to get the test process right.

Comment: The warning message doesn't say the results aren't valid.  It just says that it can't calculate an *exact* *p*-value.  As opposed to, say, an *asymptotic* *p*-value.  The *wilcoxsign_test* function has options for how to handle ties in the *zero.method* argument.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thanks! I'm kinda confused as to what method to go for. Should I use Wilcoxon signed test using `wilcoxsign_test` function or permutation test as suggested by Bruce?

Comment: I think you could use the signed-rank test or a permutation test.  For this particular data, it's pretty clear that the differences are centered on zero, so that there is no significant or meaningful change from Q1 to Q2, no matter what test you use.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I compared the p-values for both the methods. Permutation test is giving me 0.49 whereas Wilcoxon-signed test is giving 0.24. Which is more accurate? Although both the tests suggest to not reject the null hypothesis, they could differ for other data. I have 6 such similar data on which I have to conduct tests on.

Comment: I don't understand the permutation test proposed by @BruceET, so I can't endorse that specific test.  The Wilcoxon signed-rank test is the most common, simple, and accepted test for this application.  It seems like a natural choice.

Comment: @SalMangiafico. Perhaps you can explain how the version of the signed rank test you prefer is superior to `wilcox.test`. Of course, no correct test can find significance _here,_ but in what way does the version you recommend do a better job dealing with ties?

Comment: Hi, @BruceET.  I didn't endorse one function for the signed-rank test over another.  I just mentioned that "The `wilcoxsign_test` function has options for how to handle ties in the *zero.method* argument."  That is, you can choose [the Pratt or Wilcoxon method to handle ties](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/coin/versions/1.2-2/topics/SymmetryTests).

Comment: see related question for sign test https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/103162/3277

Answer (score 6):

There are two obstacles to doing a Wilcoxon signed-rank test: (a) You have only 13 non-zero differences among 21. The 0 differences provide no evidence that Q1 and Q2 differ. You may hate to 'discard' these differences, but they were never really there.  (b) There are many ties among the non-zero differences; only six unique differences among 13. Because the Wilcoxon test is based on ranks, the existence of
so many ties makes it difficult to find a P-value. I simply don't think a Wilcoxon signed rank test is useful for analyzing your data.

In principle, a simulated permutation test can obtain a reasonable approximation
of the P-value. However, that does not help find a significant difference for your data. P-values of permutation tests (one or two-sided) on your data are
much too big to lead to rejection.

The root difficulty is that 4 of the 13  nonzero differences are positive and 9 are negative, and that is too well balanced an outcome to lead to rejection. (If a fair coin is flipped 13 times, there
is better than 1 chance in 4 that it will show Heads either 4 or fewer times or 9 or more times.)

The bottom line is that your data are consistent with the null hypothesis that
Q1 and Q2 do not differ.

---

**Addendum:** Here is one possible permutation test for your data.

First, a paired t test gives test statistic $T = -0.8495$ with P-value $0.4057.$

```
t.test(d)

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = -0.8495, df = 20, p-value = 0.4057
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5759201  0.2425867
sample estimates:
 mean of x 
-0.1666667
```

The legendary robustness of the t test notwithstanding, a t test may not be appropriate for your data because they are so discrete and because they
fail a Shapiro-Wilk test of normality with P-value $0.02569.$

```
shapiro.test(d)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  d
W = 0.89302, p-value = 0.02569
```

The usefulness of the t statistic as a measure of any shift from Q1 to Q2 is
not in question. However, because the data are not normal, it is doubtful
whether the distribution of the t statistic is Student's t distribution with 20 degrees of freedom.

A permutation test is based on the idea that if there is no shift in values from Q1 to Q2, we could change the signs of the differences without harm. If we
change these signs at random many times, and compute the t statistic for each
such 'permuted' sample, then we can approximate the 'permutation distribution' of the t statistic, and use that distribution to get a reliable P-value.

There
are too many possible permutations to consider them all by combinatorial methods, but simulating many cases gives a serviceable result. The result will be 
slightly different on each run, but with 100,000 iterations not enough
different to affect the conclusion whether to reject the null hypothesis.
(Results from a program in R are shown below.)

The run below gave P-value 0.49, which is very much larger than 5%, so we
cannot reject the null hypothesis. [The P-value is not enormously different from the P-value of the t test, but enough different that doing the permutation test was worthwhile.]

```
d = c(-.5, -2, 0, 2.5, -.5,  .5, 0, -.5, -.5, -1,   0, -1, 0 ,0, 1,  0, 0, .5, -1, 0, -1)
n = length(d)
set.seed(706);  m = 10^5
t.obs = t.test(d)$stat;  pv.obs = t.test(d)$p.val
t.prm = replicate(m, t.test(d*sample(c(-1,1), n, rep=T))$stat)
p.val = mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs));  p.val
[1] 0.48816
```

The permutation distribution of the t statistic is highly discrete, but
when plotted with only a few histogram bars it is seen not to differ greatly
from Student's t distribution with 20 degrees of freedom, the
density of which is shown in the figure below.

[image]

*Reference:* [Eudey, et al. (2010)](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n1/eudey.pdf) provides an
elementary introduction to permutation tests; Sect. 3 deals with paired
designs.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET. This is super helpful. Someone from the comments said that `wilcoxsign_test` function from coin package handles ties very well. What do you think is the best method for this data: permutation test or WIlcoxon signed test?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with `wilcoxsign_test`: maybe leave a note to whoever suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

`exactRankTests::wilcox.exact()` can handle ties. It is no longer under development, the authors suggest using package `coin` instead. But it it still works.