# Zero differences and Wilcoxon signed rank test

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am wondering if the Wilcoxon signed rank test is an appropriate test for my data, that does not follow a normal distribution.

I have 150 datasheets of numbers of drugs measured at two points in time.

- 40 negative ranks (reduction in number of drugs)
- 10 positive ranks (increase in number of drugs)
- 100 zero differences

Considering the high prevalence of zero differences in around 2/3 of datasheets, is it still valid to use Wilcoxon signed rank test? Is there any reasonable alternative for nonparametric and non-continuous data?

Comment: Likely to be related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/103162/3277

Comment: Also:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73533/why-do-zero-differences-not-enter-computation-in-the-wilcoxon-signed-ranked-test